# How to find just deleted files in Time Machine?

Tags: time-machine, restore

I am going through many old photographs on my Mac, deleting duplicates that have occurred for one reason or another.  However, I realise that I may have deleted the wrong duplicate in some cases.  I have deleted several hundred duplicate photos, across multiple folders.

I have my whole hard drive backed up in Time Machine.  However I don't want to simply restore all the files in Time Machine for my photos folder since I have made some changes since doing the deletion that I want to keep.  There are too many files involved to hunt for them in Time Machine individually.

Is there a way I can identify the files in a folder in Time Machine that **do not** exist in the current filesystem?  And then a way to restore them.

I think the command line tool `tmutil` may be helpful but I am not experienced with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access time machine via a mount and then search and copy back to your machine using the automation technique of your choosing.

Here is a command you might find helpful. Replace A and B with your two directories. ([see the SO answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11440332/in-bash-find-all-files-in-flat-directory-that-dont-exist-in-another-directory-t))

```
$ comm -23 <( find A -type f -printf '%f\n' | sort | uniq ) <( find B -type f -printf '%f\n' | sort | uniq )
```

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.

Comment: @patrix I added some more details from the link. Is that the type of details you were looking for?

Comment: Thx. If you want to help the OP even further: How could the functionality described in your answer be used to solve the specific problem the OP has?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you deleted the pictures directly in Finder

- open (in Finder) the folder which used to contain the pictures
- access Time Machine via the menulet
- TM will open, showing the different time slices of your folde
- Go back in time until before the deletion
- Right-click on file(s) in question to restore them

Comment: Unfortunately I am talking about cleaning up several hundred duplicate image files, scattered across multiple folders.  The basic functionality of Time Machine is not much help - I am looking for a more automated solution.